# Count items in Arraylist that have specific attribute

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist

I want to execute code if NONE of the items in Arraylist have attribute 'slotted' set to false. I use the following code :

```
int p=0;

 for (int i = 0; i < AppleList.size();i++){
     if (AppleList.get(i).slotted = true){
        p++;
     } 

if (p == 0){

    //EXECUTE CODE

}
```

Is there any way to do this better?

Comment: `AppleList.get(i).slotted = true` should be `AppleList.get(i).slotted == true` or even better `AppleList.get(i).slotted`

Comment: by "better" do you mean more efficient/quicker? You could use a for each loop as an alternative ;)

Comment: Also, use an iterator which is faster than indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using enhanced-for loop and a label:

```
label:
{
    for(Foo f : AppleList) if(!f.slotted) break label;

    // Here you guaranteed that all slotted fields are true
}
```

Comment: Creative solution that needs no boolean variable.

Comment: This looks nice, clean and tidy! I hope to check it this weekend and will set valid answer if it works! Thnx!

Comment: Eng.Fouad, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!

Comment: @KeesKoenen I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of errors in your code. First a missing `}`, and second:

```
AppleList.get(i).slotted = true
//                       ^ should be ==
```

About your question:

> execute code if NONE of the items in Arraylist have attribute 'slotted' set to false.

Or, *all* the elements must be slotted. So if *any* element has `slotted` set to `false`, don't execute the code:

```
boolean allSloted = true;

//   VVVVV or appropriate type
for (Apple a : AppleList) {
    if (!a.slotted) {
        allSloted = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (allSloted) {
    // EXECUTE CODE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < AppleList.size() && !AppleList.get( i ).slotted; i++ ) {
}

if ( i == AppleList.size() ) {
  //EXECUTE CODE
}
```

or

```
boolean foundNonSlotted = false;
for ( int i = 0; i < AppleList.size(); i++ ) {
   if ( !AppleList.get( i ).slotted ) {
     foundNonSlotted = true;
     break;
   }
}

if ( foundNonSlotted ) {
  //EXECUTE CODE
}
```

Comment: This will execute code if at least one element is slotted, but they must _all_ be slotted: "execute code if NONE of the items in Arraylist have attribute 'slotted' set to false".

Answer (score 1):

If i where you i'll do it like this

```
boolean flag=true;

for (int i = 0; i < AppleList.size();i++){
   if (!AppleList.get(i).slotted){
      flag = false;
      break;
     }  
   } 
 if (flag){
   //EXECUTE CODE
}
```

here it may differ in performance because the big(O) may be equal (1) "I means if the first item in arraylist equal true then you need to do your code , you don't have to complete loop to be equal to arraylist size"

Comment: "I want to execute code if NONE of the items in Arraylist have attribute 'slotted' set to false" -- this means they must ALL be slotted, not just one.

Comment: instead of AppleList.get(i).slotted == true write it AppleList.get(i).slotted == false ;  just understand my way of thinking . in case your condition fail at the beginning you don't have to complete the whole array size .

Comment: You need to reverse your code execution condition. Currently you execute if you find one unslotted, but the OP says only execute code if all slotted.

Comment: Also you're missing a semi colon.

Comment: where's the missing semi colon

Comment: oh my bad! I meant curly brace, which you fixed. Do you see my point about the logic though?

Comment: and here's my update . first i assumed that all are true and in case that there is one item in array set to false then loop stop execution and the code will not be executed .